# Why update clause takes a long time while select clause (with the same logic) doesn't?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, updates

Here is a `select` query which executes in `0.03` sec:

```
select * from engine.transactions 
where transaction_row not in (select transaction_row from d.pos_transactions)
```

I want to update the matched (selected) rows from the query above this way:

```
update engine.transactions set retry = 0 
where transaction_row not in (select transaction_row from d.pos_transactions)
```

which returns `timeout` error:

> #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Why the performance drops this much on `update` clause?

---

Noted that there is only one index on `engine.transactions` table: `transactions(psp_id, transaction_row)`.

Also, the table engine is `InnoDB`

Comment: Rewrite WHERE NOT IN (which is slow in most cases) to WHERE NOT EXISTS or JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: How much records are there to be updated? Could be a locking-Problem. The dumbest thing I myself did once for a while was two work in two sessions and lock myself..., ups, typing to slow

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
update engine.transactions t left join
       d.pos_transactions pt
       using (transaction_row)
    set retry = 0 
    where pt.transaction_row is null;
```

For performance, you want an index on `d.post_transactions(transaction_row)`.  However, given the performance of the `select`, you might also have (or not need) the index.